# WiFi access point location estimation

Tags: wifi

Is there any way to determine accurate position of WiFi access points. I have come across many ways about estimating user's position by using received RSSI but can we find the actual physical location of the access point itself by using the RSSI ?

Comment: The question is interesting but put in the wrong way. You have to be a lot more specific to get some nice answers. Describe the "many ways", be more specific about "actual physical location". Is telling whether the AP is in the room enough? Or you need to be more precise? How much precise?

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly it's a relatively simple problem but a hard solution in the real world.

Triangulation is your best bet at easily determining the location of the access point in theory, move to three points take the signal strength reading and bobs your uncle your access point is one the ceiling where you left it.

But this has one critical flaw, your phone/measuring device needs an accurate frame of reference. If your indoors GPS has gone. So unless you whip out your tape measure and use some software to determine each of the three Triangulation spots accurately in 3d space it's a waste of your time. Even if you did have GPS I wouldn't call it accurate for the kind of distances that you require.

Comment: Your phone/measuring device may also have varying sensitivity depending on orientation.  One might be able to determine the orientation of maximum sensitivity and twist the device around to get a line of position at maximum signal, then intersect the lines.  Signal strength alone at only three points does not give you enough to identify the location of peak signal, just enough to estimate the slope of a plane.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly triangulation, if you could have multiple devices to test from, or you could try physically moving the device and record the signal strength. Depending on the distance from the host to the device you might have to move the device quite far to get any useful positioning information.

EDIT: signal strength could also be effected by objects in the way, but if you collect enough data you could still get a rough location.